# Socket.io Identify User for Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I write some code example that identifi connected users via socket.io... So now I must write a code on index page to comunicate with users.

The code is below and HOW to send a message to user[1] "Welcome" and for user[2] "HI men" and also limit connection fr 2 users. so when 2 user connected then anybody else cant connect..

Index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
  var users;
  socket.on('hello', function (data) {
    console.log(data.hello);
  });
  socket.on('listing', function (data) {
     users = data; 
  });
  socket.on('chat', function (message) {
     console.log(message); 
  });
  socket.on('message', function (message) {
     console.log(message); 
  });
  function chat (message) {
    socket.emit('chat', message);   
  }
  function message (user, message) {
    socket.emit('message', {
       user: user,
       message: message
    });
  }
</script>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var users = {};
var userNumber = 1;

function getUsers () {
   var userNames = [];
   for(var name in users) {
     if(users[name]) {
       userNames.push(name);  
     }
   }
   return userNames;
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var myNumber = userNumber++;
  var myName = 'user#' + myNumber;
  users[myName] = socket;

  socket.emit('hello', { hello: myName });
  io.sockets.emit('listing', getUsers());

  socket.on('chat', function (message) {
    io.sockets.emit('chat', myName + ': ' + message);
  });
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
     users[data.user].emit('message', myName + '-> ' + data.message); 
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    users[myName] = null;
    io.sockets.emit('listing', getUsers());
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: so you want to identify which user is connected to which socket ?

Comment: having variables like userNumber is fine, but definitely it will not help you in a long run, i suggest go for mongodb and start storing values in it

Comment: I need this for an example... so I want to understand how to send a different message to different user and send a message from client to server and then work with messages... so I need for example etc. to send onload message to user[1] and then when message was send to create a div who will desapire 5s - only for user 1... not for user 2... and also how to send a message to both user

Comment: is there some tutorial or something that help me to connect this with mongodb

Comment: there is no good and easy basic examples... so HOW on my script to do that? any idea

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16627225/104380

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start by taking a look at how to [configure authorization with Socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing). The `handshakeData` provided by the callback can be modified there (ie: add a username property), and any changes will be accessible via `socket.handshake` in your app.js (via the object passed in to the callback for `io.sockets.on('connection',..`). Using request header information that's also accessible from the handshakeData, you can set user values within the authorization callback (ie: from a database) so you can identify the user for the given socket in your app.js.

[Here's a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609564/socketio-mysql-authentication/10622204#10622204)

Comment: is there example with mongodb

Comment: That example is not specific to any database, there is no dB code in that answer. Head to mongoosejs.com to learn MongoDB for Node.

Comment: If looking for MongoDB for Nodejs, just grab official lib. I have experience with both and official is better then mongoose in bigger apps. With mongoose you have to learn how mongoose abstracts mongo and it's not always good thing to have. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/

Answer (score 5):

I know it has been a long time since you asked this, but just 4 days ago I published a module for node js, express and socket.io which manages that exactly thing you wanted. Check the Usage and Example; I hope you will find this module helpful!

You can install it via NPM [socket.io.users This is a node js module for socket.io applications. One user per client.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io.users)

Some of the usage code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socketUsers = require('socket.io.users');

// ...
socketUsers.Session(app); // IMPORTANT !
// ...

var rootIo = require('socket.io')(server); // default '/' as namespace. 
var chatIo = rootIo.of('/chat');

var rootUsers = socketUsers.Users; /* default '/' as namespace.
Each namespace has ITS OWN users object list,
but the Id of a user of any other namespace may 
have the same value if request comes from the same client-machine-user.
This makes easy to keep a kind of 
synchronization between all users of all the different namespaces. */

var chatUsers = socketUsers.Users.of('/chat'); //  

rootIo.use(socketUsers.Middleware());
/* IMPORTANT but no errors if you want
to skip it for a io.of(namespace) 
that you don't want the socket.io.users' support. */

chatUsers.use(socketUsers.Middleware());

chatUsers.on('connected',function(user){
console.log(user.id + ' has connected to the CHAT');
user.store.username = 'username setted by server side'; /*at the store
property you can store any type of properties
and objects you want to share between your user's sockets.  */
user.socket.on('any event', function(data){ 
/*user.socket is the current socket, to get all connected sockets from this  
user, use: user.sockets */

});
chatIo.emit('set username',user.store.username);
});

rootUsers.on('connected',function(user){
   console.log('User has connected with ID: '+ user.id);
});



rootUsers.on('connection',function(user){
   console.log('Socket ID: '+user.socket.id+' is user with ID: '+user.id);
});

rootUsers.on('disconnected',function(user){
    console.log('User with ID: '+user.id+'is gone away :(');
});

//...server.listen blabla..
```