# Keep Reference to Connected Sockets Per User

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a (for clarity's sake) a chat.

Users can login, write messages, and the others will see `[name]:[message]`.

I don't want to send the user's name and ID every time I write `socket.emit('say', message);` because that's redundant, so what I'm doing on the server is like so:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server),
    sockets = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('savePersonToSocket', function(user){
        socket.user = user;
        sockets[user.id] = socket;
    }
    socket.on('doSomething', doSomething);
});

// must be outside of 'connection' since I have TONS of these in a much more 
//complex structure and I don't want to create them all per user connection.
function doSomething(){
    ...
    sockets[userID].emit('foo'); // how to get the userID at this point?
    ...
}
```

So, how would I get the userID at that point?

**Notes:**

- For each user that logs in and connects with their Facebook account, the client will tell the server to save the person's name and ID.

I thought of doing it with a cookie that saves the user's name and ID, and the server would know which user it is by reading the cookie, but that's a bit of an ugly solution: it's redundant to send that information every time.

I could also hijack the 'on' function (somehow) and add functionality that will know which user it is, because all the 'on' listeners must reside inside the 'connection' listener anyway.

Comment: Don't get the userID. Get the socket. `socketevents.forEach(function(ev){ socket.on(ev.name, ev.fn.bind(socket)); });`

Comment: @FizzyTea - would you write it as a full answer please? I don't understand the context of your answer..how to use it.

Comment: That's just a suggestion, hence the comment and not an answer. Perhaps I should have worded it better to make it clear that I'm just *guessing*. You know your codebase better than I do, so if you can't see how it applies to you, then perhaps it's not the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, something as ugly as this should work, but the usage of `apply` is bad IMHO, and the lack of simple function pointers makes the code uglier

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('savePersonToSocket', function(user){
        socket.user = usr;
    }

    // No more simple function pointers....
    socket.on('doSomething', function(){
       // pass the Socket as the scope
       doSomething.apply(socket, arguments);
    });

});

function doSomething(){
    ...
    this.emit('foo');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is probably happening is that a user connects to your chat application, so here

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (s){
  socket = s; // cache for later usage
```

you assign "his socket" to the variable `socket` which is unbound from the context, it is on its own. Now let's say a second user arrives, `socket` gets reassigned with the second of the second user, but if you get a `savePersonToSocket` event then `socket` will be used, which is the same for everyone and more in detail it is related to the last user that connected.

There is no need for you to keep a reference to `s`, you will probably have to deal with that when you will have a lot of users connecting to your application, but the solution will be very different from your approach.

EDIT: another way could be by mapping user ids and `socket`s:

```
// this assumes that the name of a user is unique
var userSocket = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (s){
  socket.on('savePersonToSocket', function(user){
    userSocket[user.name] = s;
  }
```

So basically you are saying that you don't want to pass to `doSomething` event payload the `userID`? Because that seems like a valid solution for me, it's not redudant, it's the simplest way to let the server know about what user it is dealing with. Other solutions might be more elegant, but I doubt they are as simple and as easily maintainable as this one.

Comment: yep true that. ho, the shame of this question is killing me :)

Comment: There's no shame at all in this, don't worry ;)

Comment: yeah well after 8 years of javascript, I feel like a baby writing in Node sometimes, guessing how stuff works, because I need to think in terms of many different users and not just a single one anymore.

Comment: actually, I do need to cache the socket, because I have global functions which need access to each specific socket each time they are called.

Comment: Ok then, what about a mapping between the user and the socket?

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if that has any sense at all in your scenario.

Comment: I would still need more info about the user when he is emitting. please see my updated question

Comment: Answer updated, if that isn't what you want to do then please explain why and and expand on possible alternatives you have in mind ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you can save sockets under one account can sit a few people, for example, such a system would be:

```
var socketsList
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('auth', function (data) {
      // request to database
    if ( ! (UNIQUE_ID in socketsList)) {
         socketsList[UNIQUE_ID] = {};
         socketsList[UNIQUE_ID][socket.id] = socket;
   });
});

// ONEXIT - BROWSER EVENT
var onExit = function () { socket.emit('exit', { UNIQUE_ID : 123}) }
    window.onunload = onExit;
// 

socket.on('exit', function (data) {
   delete socketsList[UNIQUE_ID][socket.id]
})
```

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry, I'm not careful. Then this for the future :)

Comment: I fail to see how does that help with the problem

Answer (score 1):

you can't save the connection literally, it is changing quite frequently.
however you can save the socket.id. you have io.sockets.sockets[socketid]
this is probably what you are looking for.

you can save array of ids and names and reuse them if you like.

(be aware that process related variables are make it not so scaleable. but you can don't care for it the long first time :)

also you have socket related store object socket.handshake
socket.handshake.somevariable=simple_value_a_string_or_a_number

Comment: I can save the socket, it's just an object created when a person is in the system. I did save the socket ID in my earliest attempts, but still I don't see how can I later find out which user belongs to which socket, without the user passing his ID on each "emit". how can that `socket.handshake` help, by the way?

Comment: yes I can actually do save the ID of the socket (i had a problem with it ni the past when users got disconnected and the connected again, and their former socket ID meant nothing, so I would have to update their corresponding sockets' IDs and keep track of everything.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server),
    sockets = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('savePersonToSocket', function(user){
        socket.user = user;
        sockets[user.id] = socket;
    }
    socket.on('doSomething', function() { doSomething(socket.user) });
});

// must be outside of 'connection' since I have TONS of these in a much more 
//complex structure and I don't want to create them all per user connection.
function doSomething(user){
    ...
    sockets[user.id].emit('foo');
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is the worst approach...and you've also forgot to pass the arguments from the `doSomething` subscriber to the `doSomething` callback (you only passed the socket). anyway my answer is the right one

Comment: um, I passed socket.user. Remind me not to help you any more.

Comment: I suggested this because you called your own solution 'ugly.'

Comment: so you've suggested something even uglier ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time since you asked this, but Just 4 ago I published a module for node js, express and socket.io which manages that exactly thing you wanted. Check the Usage and Example, I hope you will find this module helpful!

You can install it via NPM socket.io.users [This is a node js module for socket.io applications. One user per client.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io.users)

You can loook some of the [usage code on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952032/2647655)