# How to identify users in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to build a chat application. But I don't know how to identify which user sent this message. There is no "req" (request) variable, as there is in Express. So how would I safely identify the sender in this case?

```
socket.on('chatroom message ', function(msg){
        console.log("sending msg: "+msg);
        io.emit('chatroom message ', msg);
    });
```

Comment: did you try to send userID with the message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io Identify User for Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673295/socket-io-identify-user-for-socket)

Answer (score 4):

Each Socket has a unique ID which allows you to identify the connection.

So in this case it would be

```
socket.on('chatroom message ', function(msg){
        console.log("sending msg from " + socket.id + ": "+msg);
        io.emit('chatroom message ', msg);
    });
```

The Socket.io API documentation should help
http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket