# Real time notification with socket.io and redis

Tags: php, node.js, redis, socket.io, symfony

In my web app (symfony3) I try to integrate a real time notification system.
I choose to done this with this configuration :
server NodeJS
server redis
socket.io
socket.io-php-emitter (php adaptater for emit notification directly from php)

app.js (server node)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected!');
});

io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
server.listen(8081, 'myhost');
```

test controller

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $notification = 'A message has been received by the server!<br />'
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $redis = new \Redis();
        $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
        $emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter($redis);
        $emitter->emit('notification', $notification);
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array(
            'notification' => $notification
        ));
        return $response;
    }
    return $this->render('@PMPlatform/Test/test.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

client view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Getting socket
    var socket = io('http://myhost:8081');
    // Listening on notification from server
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
        $('.server').append('qsfdqsfdqsdfqsfdqsfd');
    });
    // Listener on form submit event
    $(document).on('submit', '.form', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/app_dev.php/test',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success : function(response){
                $('.client').append('A message has been sent to server from this client!<br />');
            },
            error : function(response){
                console.log('Something went wrong.');
            },
            cache: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Ok this simple test works fine : when I submit the form from the proper view, a notification is displayed to all client which are on this page.

1- Now I want to one user be able to send a notification only to one another user (when a user comment a post, the author of the post recieved a notification). How I can do this ?

2- If the author is not connected, How I can to save the notification to show it when the author connects back ?

Comment: This is a pretty wide question if you ask me. There are plenty of ways to achieve this. One way is to store it to a database and retrieve it on page load or w/e.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, in the server you maintain in some way, redis for example, a list of all your connected clients by their sockets. But, the key thing here is to pass an id of the user when it connects to the server. Now you have your users in your socket.io server perfectly identified by their id.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket);
});
```

If you look at the socket object that comes with a connection, there you will have the id of the user that just got connected.
Then when you want to send a notfiication to that user you just have to search in redis for the corresponding socket to the user id you want to send notification. When you instantiate your emitter `$emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter($redis);` you will have to search in redis for that particular socket - search in redis by user id -

For the second question I won't go into websockets for this feature. Every time a user connects you will have to search in database if he has any pending notification, and send to him. This can be done for a small amount of users without incurring in a heavy computational usage, but this does not scale.
For this purpose I will:

- Search in redis for the connected user
- If not connected, save into database the new notification.
- When the user connects again, make a standard HTTP request to the API and send to him all the pending notifications, handling them and making necessary changes.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

I forgot to explain how you pass data on the connection. On the client just do: `var socket = io('http://216.157.91.131:8080/', { userId: "myUserId" });`. Easy, isn't it?

Comment: Ok thanks you for your explanation ! So if I understand correctly, I can't store the notification in redis db ? I have to couple the real time notification system with a traditionnal storing way (like doctrine ymsql) ?

Comment: Of course you can! But it depends on how many clients connects to your servers. If you think your infrastructure can handle without problems, just search in redis for user's pending notifications everytime you got a `io.sockets.on('connection')` event. But you will have to emit a notification by this user socket from NodeJS server, you won't be able to do it from PHP.

Comment: Ok ok, but in your post what do you mean about "If not connected, save into database the new notification." ? you talk about redis db or a traditional db like mysql ?

Comment: You can use any persistence system you like. If you use redis just take into account that it is an in-memory key-value database although persistence to disk can be enabled. You will need to write pending notifications for example being the key the userID and the value a stringify json with the notification itself.

Comment: Ok, in client view, when I try to save the user id variable with var socket = io('http://216.157.91.131:8080/', { userId: "myUserId" }); or socket.userId = "test";  and when I check in the log, and search for userId, there is no match. So there is a problem here beacause the var is not add to the socket object.

Comment: See this related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609564/socketio-mysql-authentication/10622204#10622204